# How to make canvas cursor image dynamic using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I’m building a canvas drawing app, where can I select different colors from color tool, how can I make canvas cursor image dynamic filled with selected color?
Thanks in advance, following was the code to make cursor image, but this is static cursor image, I just wanted to make this dynamic filled with selected color from color tool.

```
.circle64 {
  cursor: url('http://www.iconsdownload.net/icons/64/16574-black-circle.png'), pointer;
}
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779354/assign-color-to-mouse-cursor-using-css (check 2nd answer)

Comment: no, its showing different color while pointing in canvas

Comment: But you can see the code for changing the arrow's color, now you need to use that information in your code, attach that code to whatever you want the user to do in order for the cursor to change color (e.g. clicking a colored square).