# Javascript library to Change cursor color

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, cursor

I am working on a user drawing tool and when they select a different color to draw with I was hoping to chance there pen shaped cursor to that color.  Because they can have 16,777,216 possible colors, I am not able create that many images to simply change their cursor with cursor: url().

CSS Example
    `cursor: url();`

Does anyone know of a JavaScript or Canvas solution for this problem?

Comment: This answer looks promising:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18779917/3903374

Comment: I searched for a solid 30 minutes before posting.  Thank you VERY much!  The second answer, obviously the first one/Accepted is garbage.